# ERROR 001269 : Compressing the service definition failed.ArcGIS 10.1,Python 2.7

Tags: arcgis-10.1, c#, python-2.7

I am trying to publish an mxd using python script. I invoke this pyhton script from c# application, after creating the sddraft file, the system throws up this error "001269 : Compressing the service definition failed."
I looked up online and it says that it gives this kind of error with 64 bit python, I was using python for visual studio(not Iron Python). And it also says online that "ArcGIS for Desktop was still using the 32 bits"
Is there a way to publish the mxd or anything else which I should consider? Any help on this is most welcome.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has a suggestion for this.

Comment: I tried putting this on Iron Python 64 bit, but it doesnt have arcpy library. Really donot know what to do. The geoprocessing library for ArcGIS desktop is 64 bit, the the current arcpy I am using is 32 bit and I guess that is causing the problem

Comment: Did you resolve? I'm having the same problem using (what I think is) 64 bit python with PyScripter

*** Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. ***

Comment: I was using 64bit python. Downloading the 32 bit version of PyScripter resolved for me. This was useful: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/07/29/64-bit-vs-32-bit-python-explained/